# Listbox in dynamic web user controls lost data after postback

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, postback

I create dynamic web user control which has a list box and a textbox. However, data in the list box is lost after postback but the data in the textbox isn't.

I've read a lot of forums and pages about web user controls and I understands that web user controls recreate after such post-back.

Could you please show me the way to get data of list box before post back ?

Thank alot 
'--------------------------------------
Note that: my web user control has a list and text boxes, user can add value to the list box by entering values in the text box ( I wrote functions in javascripts to add data from text box to list box)  .

However, in the main page, when I click a button to save data of the list, all of my page and my web user control are reloaded, so data in the list box is also disappear :-(

Code VB for adding web user control:

```
Private Sub WebFormTestValidation_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

        Dim ctrList As wucListPerson
        ctrList = LoadControl("wucListPerson.ascx")
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(ctrList)
        ctrList.ID = "wucDynamic"     
        ctrList.wucName = "DYNAMIC TEST"
        ctrList.wucInfo = "DYNAMIC TEST"
    End Sub
```

'----------------------

Code VB of web user control

```
Public Class wucListPerson
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
    Public Property lstPersons As List(Of String)
        Get
            Dim lst As New List(Of String)
            If lstFullName.Items.Count > 0 Then
                For i = 0 To lstFullName.Items.Count - 1
                    lst.Add(CStr(lstFullName.Items(i).Value))
                Next
            End If
            Return lst
        End Get

        Set(ByVal lstValues As List(Of String))
            If lstValues.Count > 0 Then
                For i = 0 To lstValues.Count - 1
                    Dim strArr As String() = Split(CStr(lstValues.Item(i)), "*")
                    Ordre.Text = CStr(strArr(0))
                    Nom.Text = strArr(1)
                    Prenom.Text = strArr(2)
                    hdfIdPersonne.Value = strArr(3)
                    Dim item As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem
                    item.Text = strArr(0) + "." + strArr(1) + " " + strArr(2)
                    item.Value = CStr(lstValues.Item(i))
                    lstFullName.Items.Add(item)
                Next
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property wucName As String
        Get
            Return lblName.Text
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As String)
            lblName.Text = value

        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property wucInfo As String
        Get
            Return Info.Text

        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Info.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub addPersonne(ByVal ordre As Integer, ByVal nom As String, ByVal prenom As String, idpersonne As Integer)
        'lstName.Items.Add(CStr(ordre) + "." + nom + " " + prenom, CStr(ordre) + "*" + nom + "*" + prenom + "*" + CStr(idpersonne))
        Dim item As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem
        item.Text = CStr(ordre) + "." + nom + " " + prenom
        item.Value = CStr(ordre) + "*" + nom + "*" + prenom + "*" + CStr(idpersonne)
        lstFullName.Items.Add(item)

    End Sub

    Public Function getList() As List(Of String)
        Dim lst As New List(Of String)
        If lstFullName.Items.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To lstFullName.Items.Count - 1
                lst.Add(CStr(lstFullName.Items(i).Value))
            Next
        End If
        Return lst
    End Function
    Public Sub SetList(ByVal lst As List(Of String))
        If lst.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To lst.Count - 1
                Dim strArr As String() = Split(CStr(lst.Item(i)), "*")
                Ordre.Text = CStr(strArr(0))
                Nom.Text = strArr(1)
                Prenom.Text = strArr(2)
                hdfIdPersonne.Value = strArr(3)
                Dim item As New ListItem
                item.Text = strArr(0) + "." + strArr(1) + " " + strArr(2)
                item.Value = CStr(lst.Item(i))
                lstFullName.Items.Add(item)
            Next
        End If

    End Sub
    Protected uniqueKey As String
    Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        '    lblName.Text = wucName
        'End If
        Me.uniqueKey = Guid.NewGuid.ToString("N")
        Me.cmdRight.Attributes("onclick") = ("RemoveItem_" + (uniqueKey + "(); return false;"))
        Me.cmdLeft.Attributes("onclick") = ("AddItem_" + (uniqueKey + "(); return false;"))
        Me.cmdInfor.Attributes("onclick") = ("showHideInfor_" + (uniqueKey + "(); return false;"))
        If Trim(lblName.Text) = "" Then cmdInfor.Visible = False
    End Sub


End Class
```

'----------------------
Code Javascript to get/ remove data from text boxes to the list

//===================

```
function getMaxOrdre_<%=uniqueKey%>() {

    var listName = document.getElementById("<%=lstFullName.ClientID()%>");
    var lst = listName.options;

    var count = lst.length;
    if (lst.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    var max = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var item = lst[i].value;
        var FName = getFullName_<%=uniqueKey%>(item);           
        if (parseInt(FName.Ordre) > max) {
            max = FName.Ordre;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
//===================
function getFullName_<%=uniqueKey%>(FullName) {
    if (FullName.length != "0") {
        var temp = new Array();
        temp = FullName.split('*');
        return { Ordre: temp[0], Nom: temp[1], PreNom: temp[2], IdPersonne: temp[3] };
    }
    return { Ordre: 0, Nom: '', PreNom: '', IdPersonne: '0' };
}
//===================
function AddItem_<%=uniqueKey %>() {
    //lstName.BeginUpdate();
    var txtOrdre = document.getElementById("<%=Ordre.ClientID()%>");
    var txtNom = document.getElementById("<%=Nom.ClientID()%>");
    var txtPrenom = document.getElementById("<%=Prenom.ClientID()%>");
    var hdfIdPerson = document.getElementById("<%=hdfIdPersonne.ClientID%>");

    var listName = document.getElementById("<%=lstFullName.ClientID()%>");
    var index = listName.selectedIndex;
    var lst = listName.options;

    var ordre = txtOrdre.value;
    var nom = txtNom.value;
    var prenom = txtPrenom.value;
    var idPerson = hdfIdPerson.value;
    if ((nom.length > 0) || (prenom.length > 0)) {

        var selectBoxOption = document.createElement("option");//create new option
        selectBoxOption.value = ordre + '*' + nom + '*' + prenom + '*' + idPerson;//set option value
        selectBoxOption.text = ordre + '.' + nom + ' ' + prenom;//set option display text
        listName.add(selectBoxOption, null);//add created option to select box. 
    };

   // lstName.EndUpdate();
    //get deafault data
    var ordreMax = getMaxOrdre_<%=uniqueKey%>();

    txtOrdre.value = parseInt(ordreMax) + 1;
    txtNom.value = '';
    txtPrenom.value = '';
    hdfIdPerson.value = '0';


}
//===================
function RemoveItem_<%=uniqueKey %>() {

    //lstName.BeginUpdate();
    var txtOrdre = document.getElementById("<%=Ordre.ClientID()%>");
    var txtNom = document.getElementById("<%=Nom.ClientID()%>");
    var txtPrenom = document.getElementById("<%=Prenom.ClientID()%>");
    var hdfIdPerson = document.getElementById("<%=hdfIdPersonne.ClientID%>");
    var listName = document.getElementById("<%=lstFullName.ClientID()%>");
    var index = listName.selectedIndex;      
    var lst = listName.options;
    if (index >= 0) {
        var FName = getFullName_<%=uniqueKey %>(lst[index].value);
        txtOrdre.value = FName.Ordre;
        txtNom.value = FName.Nom;
        txtPrenom.value = FName.PreNom;
        hdfIdPerson.value = FName.IdPersonne;

        listName.remove(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code to create your usercontrol.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've edited my question and I hope that you can help me solve this problem.

Comment: Can you now show the code that binds the data to the list?

Comment: As your requirement, I've added Code Vb and java script of my web user control.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are adding the new items in the `DOM`, but these changes will not necessarily be reflected in your `ListBox` after a page refresh or `PostBack`. I could suggest two solutions:

1) Add the elements in the `ListBox` through .net instead of using Javascript.

but if  you need a client side solution so that your page won't refresh everytime you add an item:

2) Add a .net `HiddenField` control. These controls have the advantage of being accessible easily from both Client Side and Server Side. You can add each item in both, the `ListItem` and the `HiddenField` (maybe comma separated) and on the server side you will use this `HiddenField` instead of your `ListBox`.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I use your 2nd solution, I have to write a function javascript to manage Hiddenfield in each time list Item changed?

Comment: Once more time, thank you very much, I use your 2 nd solution and it works